# Completar enlace href con el texto libre escrito luego de /?h= en la URL

Tags: javascript

quisiwera si me pueden resolver esta consulta.
Tengo esta linea para añadir un parametro a la URL de destino.
La misma es una constante en este acaso. Ahora necesito que sea distinto, tengo más de un button.

Necesito que se redireccione a distintas carpetas que estan en el mismo .public_html , que puedo identificar cada boton con  por ejemplo

```
    <a href:"nombre_de_carpeta/?clickh1=" onclick="redirectTo();">pulsa aqui</a>

    <a href:"nombre_de_carpeta_1/?clickh2=" onclick="redirectTo();">pulsa aqui2</a>
```

Necesito que la URL de destino sea  url + "nombre_de_carpeta/?clickh1="+ param;

```
<input id="completar_url" type="text" />
<button>
    <a onclick="redirectTo();">pulsa aqui</a>
</button>

function redirectTo() {
    const url = "http://miweb.com/?h=";
    let param = document.getElementById('completar_url').value; 
    window.location.href = url + param;
}
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Los atributos en HTML se asignan con `=`, no con `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu script no estás considerando que al hacer clic en los enlaces, el navegador irá directo a la ubicación definida en el atributo `href` y, probablemente, no se pueda hacer la redirección.

Te sugiero que en lugar de colocar el evento `onclick` en cada enlace, le asignes una clase y, posteriormente, con javascript se agrega el evento.

Dentro de la función cancelas el comportamiento normal (que el navegador vaya a la página del enlace), armas la URL con sus parámetros y haces la redirección.

```js
const url = "http://miweb.com/?h=";

// Obtener todos los links con clase redir
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.redir');
// Agregar evento clic
links.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', redirectTo));

// Función para redirigir
function redirectTo(e) {
    // Evitar comportamiento normal del enlace
    e.preventDefault();
    // Obtener parámetro (e.target es el enlace en que se hizo clic)
    let carpeta = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    // Agregar contenido del campo de texto
    let param = document.querySelector('#completar_url').value;
    // Redirigir a la URL deseada
    window.location.href = url + carpeta + param;
}
```

```html
<input id="completar_url" type="text" /><br>
<a href="nombre_de_carpeta/?clickh1=" class="redir">pulsa aqui</a><br>
<a href="nombre_de_carpeta_1/?clickh2=" class="redir">pulsa aqui2</a>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo hice asi como me indicaste y anduvo lo mas bien.

Comment: Si te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Podes probar pasarle el parametro en la funcion

HTML

```html
<a href="nombre_de_carpeta/?clickh1=" onclick="redirectTo("parametro1");">pulsa aqui</a>

    <a href="nombre_de_carpeta_1/?clickh2=" onclick="redirectTo("parametro2");">pulsa aqui2</a>
```

JS

```js
<input id="completar_url" type="text" />
<button>
    <a onclick="redirectTo();">pulsa aqui</a>
</button>

function redirectTo(param) {
    const url = "http://miweb.com/?h=";
    window.location.href = url + param;
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar el nombre de la carpeta como parámetro directmente desde el `onclick`.

No es recomendable poner un link dentro de un `button`, por eso lo he quitado.

Si quieres encadenar [query params](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) tienes que usar `&`.
Por ejemplo, `http://miweb.com/?h=valor1&param2=valor2&param3=valor3`

```js
function redirectTo(nombreCarpeta) {
    const url = "http://miweb.com/?h=";
    const param = document.getElementById('completar_url').value; 
    const nuevaUrl = url + nombreCarpeta +'&clickh1=' + param;
    
    // window.location.href = nuevaUrl; descomenta esto en tu script
    console.log(nuevaUrl)
}
```

```html
<input id="completar_url" type="text" />

    
<button onclick="redirectTo('carpeta1');">pulsa aqui</button>
<button onclick="redirectTo('carpeta2');">pulsa aqui2</button>
```